# Casting unknown type to know type

Tags: rust

So I have this function

```
fn render_i32(n: &dyn Typeable, echo: &dyn Fn(&String)) {
    let x: &i32 = unsafe {transmute(n)};
    echo(&x.to_string());
}
```

It does not compile because `cannot transmute between types of different sizes`.

What I want with this code is the following: I have a `HashMap` which contains rendering functions for different types. Every type that may be rendered must implement my interface `Typeable`, which basically only returns a constant `type_id` for the type (I've just come across a `type_id` in std, and wonder if I could use that instead...). And using that `type_id` I can then look up the correct render function in my `HashMap`. So my code ensures, that `render_i32` is only called for `i32`. This works fine.

Now all of this would be really easy in C where I'd just cast the value under the pointer. But in rust it does not appear to be so easy. I don't get at the i32 value. How would I get that?

**Edit**: Alternative Solutions to my own approach that are less type-unsafe but solve the following requirement are also welcome: clients (who use this library) should be able to add their own rendering functions for their own types...

Note that the rendering functions are not supposed to be statically defined once: different rendering functions might be used for the same type depending for example on a language setting.

Comment: Does it really need to be that unsafe-ish? Did you consider some more type safe approaches like enums + macros?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov well I'm relatively new at rust, so I might be overlooking a better approach. But one of the requirements is, that clients can add arbitrary rendering functions for arbitrary types. I would be happy if anyone could provide me with a more rusty way of doing this...

Comment: You can implement the `Any` trait for the `Typeable` trait, maybe

Comment: Can you invert it: put the `render()` function on the `Typeable` trait (it should probably be called `Renderable` then), and pass it some arguments that allow implementations to delegate to the correct rendering function depending on some settings?

Comment: @Thomas well that is possible I suppose. I have a similar problem then, that the settings I pass might also be arbitrary and user-dependent...

Comment: Or you could do it all statically: `trait Renderable<T> { fn render(options: &T); }`. The generic type `T` is contagious: whatever structs/functions contain `Renderable`s would also need to be generic over `T`. If you need to do something with `T` in your own code (as opposed to client code), you can restrict `T` to implement some `RenderOptions` trait as well, and require that your clients also implement `RenderOptions` if they want to use their own type here.

Comment: In that scenario, you can still have different `Renderable` implementations for a type: just wrap it in a newtype struct. Define `struct One(Foo);` and `struct Two(Foo);` with `impl Renderable<T> for One { ... }` and `impl Renderable<T> for Two { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the [`Any` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) for your purpose:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

pub trait Typeable {
   ...
   fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

fn render_i32(n: &dyn Typeable, echo: &dyn Fn(&String)) {
    let x: &i32 = n.as_any().downcast_ref::<i32>().unwrap();
    echo(&x.to_string());
}
```

The `downcast_ref::<i32>()` method returns an `Option<&i32>`, so you can also check if the downcast is valid. You can even do this in a generic way:

```rust
fn render<T:'static + std::fmt::Display>(n: &dyn Typeable, echo: &dyn Fn(&String)) {
    let x: &T = n.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap();
    echo(&x.to_string());
}
```

Comment: I accept this as the answer, because it actually solves the original question. But I'll try and go with a more rustacian approach...

Answer (score 2):

I still don't get why you didn't use the conventional `trait`-`impl` approach, it seems to do what you wanted, except that function pointers don't have any common data structure holding them (it's probably less cache-friendly than `HashMap`'s approach)

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=90df87e110d33c4f2724424eed127d9e)

```
use std::iter;

// lib
fn echo_windows(s: &String) {
    println!("C:/Users> {}", s)
}

fn echo_linux(s: &String) {
    println!("$ {}", s)
}

trait Renderable {
    fn render(&self, echo: &dyn Fn(&String));
}

// client
struct ClientType {
    ch: char,
    len: usize,
}

impl Renderable for ClientType {
    fn render(&self, echo: &dyn Fn(&String)) {
        let to_echo: String = iter::repeat(self.ch)
            .take(self.len)
            .collect();
        echo(&to_echo);
    }
}


fn main() {
    ClientType{ ch: '#', len: 5 }.render(&echo_windows); // output: C:/Users> #####
    ClientType{ ch: '!', len: 3 }.render(&echo_linux);   // output: $ !!!
}
```

Comment: This may be the most rustacean approach. However, you can only define one `render` function per data type, isn't it?

Comment: I'll have to think about that approach. Combined with @Thomas comment (to add some configuration data as a second argument to the render function) this too might solve my requirement...

Comment: @RománCárdenas multi-render option would definitely be tricky, but for the time being it can be easily solved with separate traits like `GuiRenderable` `ConsoleRenderable`, etc. All of them may either have different `render_*` functions, or the same `render` function, accessed by trait name